# Is there a way to create a dictionary in Python where the values are added from a specific index from a list of lists?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from a list of lists (similarly to how a csv file is read using a for loop in Python) where the keys are unique values in the first 'column' and the keys are the sum of the values in the corresponding 'column'
This is the structure I have so far:

```
animal_dict = {}
animals1 = ['cat', 1]
animals2 = ['dog', 2]
animals3 = ['cat', 1]
animals4 = ['dog', 1]

animals = [animals1, animals2, animals3, animals3, animals4]
for i in animals:
    animal_dict[i[0]] = animal_dict.get(i[0], 0) + i[1]
```

From this code, I want the dictionary to look like this:

```
{'cat': 2, 'dog': 3}
```

However, when I run the above code, `animal_dict` shows as

```
{'cat': 3, 'dog': 3}
```

I know the issue is coming from the `animal_dict.get(i[0], 0)` part of the code, but I don't know how to change the code for it to do what I want

Comment: Why do you think `'cat'` should only be counted twice? In your algorithm, `i` attains the value `['cat', 1]` three times - once when `animals1` is processed, and twice when `animals3` is. Your algorithm has no way of telling that `animals3` only needs to be processed once.

Answer (score 1):

You have animals3 in your list twice. Remove that and it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

you have added `animals3` in `animals` 2 times
change animals with below line:

```
animals = [animals1, animals2, animals3, animals4]
```